# I change (rewrite) URL with jquery but when user or I refresh the page, we get 404 not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I rewrite URL like this,

```
history.pushState('data', '', 'http://radyospor.fstats.net/Galatasaray-Bursa');
```

Everything is good but after rewrite url when refresh page I get to:

> "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you created a route or page that actually exists and matches this path? If not, do that. You can't just expect to update the URL of a browser and for it to resolve to something.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your home page is at this URL: `http://radyospor.fstats.net/`
When you browse to that URL, the server returns the `index.html` file which is found in its web root.

When you call `history.pushState`, there is no call to the server but the URL is changed.

When you refresh after `history.pushState`, the URL is now `http://radyospor.fstats.net/Galatasaray-Bursa` which the server interprets as a request to a file named `Galatasaray-Bursa` in the web root directory.
This file does not exist, so you get a 404.

### The solution

1. You need to serve index.html for requests to files that don't exist.
   Depending on where your app is hosted, this might be a configuration of the web server (EG nginx) or a configuration of the hosting service.
2. The Javascript code in index.html will need to read the current URL and display the relevant content accordingly.
   Assuming you don't use a framework like ReactJs, you can use something like [page.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js) to handle the routing